# how to get the context of "chrome f12" through python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, debugging

how to get the context of google-chrome debugging windows through Python?

eg: chrome -> f12 -> network -> Select a file -> copy -> copy as cURL

Because many parameters cannot be provided completely when using `response = requests.get(url, headers, params)` to access that file, Errors may occur, but the function of "copy as cURL" can work well.

actually, I want to get the content in the "Copy as cURL" through python code, rather than manually copying it.

I can not upload picture as my reputation value is too slow, hope you understand what I mean.

I'm sorry for that.

Comment: From Review: You may provide a link to your screenshots, other users will embed it into your answer. If you could also provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would help people find a solution for you.

Comment: Avoid screenshots as much as you can!